# kubectl create secret generic InternalError PermissionDenied

Tags: kubernetes

I've configured access to my K8s cluster, set up all needed pods &services, created secrets with YAML files, but this simple command:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-literal=key1=supersecret --from-literal=key2=topsecret
kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file=path/to/bar
```

Leads to an error:

> Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: rpc error: code = Internal desc = kms service encrypt error: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Permission denied

How can I solve this??

More details: the cluster get running on [Yandex cloud](https://cloud.yandex.com). Of course I've wrote to the support, but I hope to get a quicker solution response here.

**Update.**. Some roles info:

```
kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings --all-namespaces


NAMESPACE    NAME    ROLE    AGE
kube-public   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:bootstrap-signer    Role/system:controller:bootstrap-signer    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler    Role/cluster-autoscaler    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader    Role/extension-apiserver-authentication-reader    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/node-metrics-agent-rb    Role/node-metrics-agent    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system::extension-apiserver-authentication-reader   Role/extension-apiserver-authentication-reader    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system::leader-locking-kube-controller-manager    Role/system::leader-locking-kube-controller-manager   15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system::leader-locking-kube-scheduler    Role/system::leader-locking-kube-scheduler    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:bootstrap-signer    Role/system:controller:bootstrap-signer    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:cloud-provider    Role/system:controller:cloud-provider    15d
kube-system   rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:token-cleaner    Role/system:controller:token-cleaner    15d
monitoring    rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/loki    Role/loki    14d
monitoring    rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/loki-promtail    Role/loki-promtail    14d
monitoring    rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-grafana    Role/prom-grafana    14d
monitoring    rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-grafana-test    Role/prom-grafana-test    14d
monitoring    rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-alertmanager    Role/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-alertmanager    14d


NAMESPACE   NAME    ROLE    AGE
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ccm-binding    ClusterRole/cluster-admin    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-admin    ClusterRole/cluster-admin    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler    ClusterRole/cluster-autoscaler    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-attacher-binding    ClusterRole/external-attacher-role    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-csinodeinfos-reader-binding    ClusterRole/csinodeinfos-reader    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-csinodes-reader-binding    ClusterRole/csinodes-reader    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-driver-registrar-binding    ClusterRole/cluster-driver-registrar-role    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-endpoints-reader-binding    ClusterRole/endpoints-operator    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-leases-operator-binding    ClusterRole/leases-operator    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-provisioner-binding    ClusterRole/external-provisioner-role    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-snapshotter-binding    ClusterRole/external-snapshotter-role    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/event-logger-rb    ClusterRole/view    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/loki-promtail-clusterrolebinding    ClusterRole/loki-promtail-clusterrole    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator    ClusterRole/system:auth-delegator    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress    ClusterRole/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/node-metrics-agent-rb    ClusterRole/node-metrics-agent    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/npd-binding    ClusterRole/system:node-problem-detector    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/npd-ds-binding    ClusterRole/system:node-problem-detector    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-grafana-clusterrolebinding    ClusterRole/prom-grafana-clusterrole    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-operator    ClusterRole/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-operator    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-operator-psp    ClusterRole/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-operator-psp    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus    ClusterRole/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-psp    ClusterRole/prom-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-psp    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/prom-kube-state-metrics    ClusterRole/prom-kube-state-metrics    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/psp-prom-kube-state-metrics    ClusterRole/psp-prom-kube-state-metrics    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/psp-prom-prometheus-node-exporter    ClusterRole/psp-prom-prometheus-node-exporter    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:basic-user    ClusterRole/system:basic-user    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:attachdetach-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:attachdetach-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:certificate-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:certificate-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:clusterrole-aggregation-controller   ClusterRole/system:controller:clusterrole-aggregation-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:cronjob-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:cronjob-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:daemon-set-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:daemon-set-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:deployment-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:deployment-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:disruption-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:disruption-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:endpoint-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:endpoint-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:endpointslice-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:endpointslice-controller    14d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:expand-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:expand-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:generic-garbage-collector    ClusterRole/system:controller:generic-garbage-collector    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:horizontal-pod-autoscaler    ClusterRole/system:controller:horizontal-pod-autoscaler    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:job-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:job-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:namespace-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:namespace-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:node-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:node-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:persistent-volume-binder    ClusterRole/system:controller:persistent-volume-binder    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:pod-garbage-collector    ClusterRole/system:controller:pod-garbage-collector    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:pv-protection-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:pv-protection-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:pvc-protection-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:pvc-protection-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:replicaset-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:replicaset-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:replication-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:replication-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:resourcequota-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:resourcequota-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:route-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:route-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:service-account-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:service-account-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:service-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:service-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:statefulset-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:statefulset-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:controller:ttl-controller    ClusterRole/system:controller:ttl-controller    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:coredns    ClusterRole/system:coredns    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:discovery    ClusterRole/system:discovery    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:kube-controller-manager    ClusterRole/system:kube-controller-manager    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:kube-dns    ClusterRole/system:kube-dns    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:kube-dns-autoscaler    ClusterRole/system:kube-dns-autoscaler    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:kube-proxy    ClusterRole/system:node-proxier    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:kube-scheduler    ClusterRole/system:kube-scheduler    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server    ClusterRole/system:metrics-server    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:node    ClusterRole/system:node    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:node-proxier    ClusterRole/system:node-proxier    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:public-info-viewer    ClusterRole/system:public-info-viewer    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:volume-scheduler    ClusterRole/system:volume-scheduler    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/yc:admin    ClusterRole/cluster-admin    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/yc:alpha:auto-approve-csrs-for-group    ClusterRole/system:certificates.k8s.io:certificatesigningrequests:nodeclient    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/yc:alpha:auto-approve-renewals-for-nodes    ClusterRole/system:certificates.k8s.io:certificatesigningrequests:selfnodeclient   15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/yc:alpha:create-csrs-for-bootstrapping    ClusterRole/system:node-bootstrapper    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/yc:editor    ClusterRole/edit    15d
    clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/yc:viewer    ClusterRole/view    15d
```

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-encryption-provider/issues/46

Comment: @RobEvans Hi! I've seen this issue, but I don't think it's relevant, I don't use AWS nor `EncryptionConfiguration` configs.

Comment: Hi there. Quick question. Are you cluster admin? What `ClusterRole` s and `Role` s does your account have in the cluster?

Comment: @JustinTamblyn Hi! I'm not yet experienced with K8s roles, but I used a command to grep it, you can see results in the Q update.

Comment: Awesome. I suspect the K8s cluster needs a key or something to talk to KMS. This is a silly question but may I ask if you setup your cluster with credentials or something to talk to Yandex KMS (sorry I don't know anything about Yandex) ? https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/kms/

Comment: @JustinTamblyn I guess I used [this guide](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/managed-kubernetes/operations/create-static-conf) to setup access. I also just found [this instruction "Encrypting secrets"](https://cloud.yandex.com/docs/managed-kubernetes/operations/encrypting-secrets), maybe I also should follow it... I'll try later. But could you please explain why I'm able to create secrets using YAML files with `stringData`, and not able using CLI, what's the difference, and how to fix it?

Comment: @JustinTamblyn I just checked that instruction and found that I've already setup encryption key for the cluster. I dunno, but maybe I have to link it with my `kubectl` or some other action is required? The support haven't responded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I had to set the role `kms.keys.encrypterDecrypter` to the service account which is used to control Kubernetes cluster in the settings of Yandex.Cloud project catalog.